# Change the text of clicked element with 'this' in JavaScript / jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

Can anybody explain is `this` in the callback.

Example.
Web page.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" id="btn001">Show</button><br/>
  <p id="p001" class="article">Some contents...</p>
  <button type="button" id="btn002">Show</button><br/>
  <p id="p002" class="article">Other content...</p>
  <!-- more paragraphs -->
</body>
</html>
```

First, I had written a function for each paragraph. Source code of the *myApp.js*.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // hide all articles at the begining
  $(".article").hide();
  // button 1 hides/shows first paragraph
  $("#btn001").click(function () {
    if ($(this).html() === "Show") {
      $(this).html("Hide");
    } else {
      $(this).html("Show");
    }
    $("#p001").toggle();
  });
  // button 2 hides/shows second paragraph
  $("#btn002").click(function () {
    if ($(this).html() === "Show") {
      $(this).html("Hide");
    } else {
      $(this).html("Show");
    }
    $("#p002").toggle();
  });
  // repeat code for next paragraphs
});
```

I get angry with the code repetition, so I tried excluding code to function.

```
function handleHideShow(par) {
  if ($(this).html() === "Show") {
    $(this).html("Hide");
  } else {
    $(this).html("Show");
  }
  par.toggle();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // hide all articles at the begining
  $(".article").hide();
  // button 1 hides/shows first paragraph
  $("#btn001").click(function () {
    handleHideShow($("#p001"));
  });
  // button 2 hides/shows second paragraph
  $("#btn002").click(function () {
    handleHideShow($("#p002"));
  });
});
```

Toggling paragraphs works, but the text on the `button` is not changing. Can anybody explain what happens to `this`?

- Why in the first example `$(this)` selects the clicked element?
- What is `$(this)` in the second example?

And how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first function is an event handler. With Event handlers `$(this)`  automatically refers to the element that was clicked, changed, hovered, etc.. jQuery creates `$(this)` for you and, while you can't explicitly see it passed into the function it is available to all the code within the click handler's callback.

Your second function is a simple function and is not an event handler therefore jQuery does not create the `$(this)` reference for you

In your code, you could pass `$(this)` from your event handler like `handleHideShow($(this),$("#p002"));` and reference it in your function like `function handleHideShow(btn, par)`. Then, inside `handleHideShow`, `btn` will refer to the same element as `$(this)` referred to in your click handler (see the second snippet below).

**But, I would simplify the code alltogether by giving the buttons and paragraphs classes instead of ids and doing this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.article').hide();
  $('.myBtn').click(function(){
    $(this).html( $(this).html() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' :'Show' );
    $(this).nextAll('.article').first().toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
      <script src="myApp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button type="button" class="myBtn">Show</button><br/>
      <p class="article">Some contents...</p>
      
      <button type="button" class="myBtn">Show</button><br/>
      <p class="article">Other content...</p>
      <!-- more paragraphs -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now, one could argue that this is less efficient as jQuery has to search through more elements to find the paragraph but I believe it to be more robust as you can add as many buttons and paragraphs as you like without worrying about all the sequential `id`s. And honestly, you'd have to have a pretty giant webpage to see any performance issues.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // hide all articles at the begining
  $(".article").hide();
  // button 1 hides/shows first paragraph
  $("#btn001").click(function () {
    handleHideShow($(this),$("#p001"));
  });
  // button 2 hides/shows second paragraph
  $("#btn002").click(function () {
    handleHideShow($(this),$("#p002"));
  });
});

function handleHideShow(btn, par) {
  if (btn.html() === "Show") {
    btn.html("Hide");
  } else {
    btn.html("Show");
  }
  par.toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" id="btn001">Show</button><br/>
  <p id="p001" class="article">Some contents...</p>
  
  <button type="button" id="btn002">Show</button><br/>
  <p id="p002" class="article">Other content...</p>
  <!-- more paragraphs -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both solutions work fine. Using single class for each button and selecting next `.article` is great. And can remove `br` or put two `br`s still works fine. Passing the reference is more suited to `this` problem I had. I guess they both useful for particular cases.

Comment: Would you mind telling is `this` problem jQuery-specific or JavaScript-specific.

Comment: @user2793410 take a look through the comments and functions here:  http://jsfiddle.net/417w0df4/2/ this should give you a good idea of how to use `this`

Answer (score 1):

The function is called with no special context, and `this` is not the element.
Reference the function instead

```
$("#btn001").click(handleHideShow);
$("#btn002").click(handleHideShow);

function handleHideShow() {
    $(this).html(function (_, html) {
        return html === "Show" ? "Hide" : "Show";
    });

    $('#' + this.id.replace('btn', 'p')).toggle();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLmtu4pr/2/)

Comment: Now you're toggling the visibility of the button instead of the paragraph.

Comment: @adaneo **1.** I missed your css (saw it in the FIDDLE) and the buttons where doing the opposite. **2.** Script should be placed after body or the 2 assignments had to be placed in the `$( document ).ready()`.

Comment: @user2793410 - where you put the script is up to you, as long as the elements are available. If you need to toggle the other way, just swap the order of the text, updated the answer to do that, I just assumed the elements would be hidden since the button text you used was "Show"

Comment: @adaneo **3.** The script works fine only when corresponding `p` and `button`  have `id`s with same suffix. For example p**001** - btn**001**. That is 100% correct assumption in my case of course.

Comment: @adaneo **4.** Would you mind explaining `$(this).html(function (_, html) {` line. **5.** What happens to the `event` argument?

Comment: The event argument isn't used, it could be remove, I just added it to show what's being passed. The above function is jQuery's `html()` function with a callback documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

Comment: @adeneo Now is see html is old HTML. What does is `_` for the first argument *the index position of the element in the set* mean?

Comment: is there any benefit to doing this over `$(this).html( $(this).html() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' :'Show' );` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the object of button in the function:

Try this:

```
function handleHideShow(par,that) {
  if ($(that).html() === "Show") {
    $(that).html("Hide");
  } else {
    $(that).html("Show");
  }
  par.toggle();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // hide all articles at the begining
  $(".article").hide();
  // button 1 hides/shows first paragraph
  $("#btn001").click(function () {
    handleHideShow($("#p001"),this);
  });
  // button 2 hides/shows second paragraph
  $("#btn002").click(function () {
    handleHideShow($("#p002"),this);
  });
});
```

Or you try this also:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // hide all articles at the begining
  $(".article").hide();
  // button 1 hides/shows first paragraph
  $("button[id^='btn']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).html() === "Show") {
      $(this).html("Hide");
    } else {
      $(this).html("Show");
    }
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

The above code is optimal and you can add buttons as many as you want.

Comment: @CodeLover Second solution is not working. Should **[** be unbalanced?

Comment: @user2793410 sorry i have forgot to add ] check update.

Comment: @CodeLღver wont  `$(this).next().toggle();` toggle the <br> tag  and not the paragraph?

Comment: @DelightedD0D is right. In my document next element after the button is `<br>`. Had to changed it to `$(this).next().next().toggle();`.