# How can I put two functions (one must delay) in one onclick button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, animation

I have a problem to combine to functions in one onclick button. This is how my product have to look like: I want to put a hammer down when I click on an invisible button, when the hammer reaches an icon, the icon has te become another picture.

This is the code I have, but it's in javascript and jquery:

```
$('.box hammer').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});

function changeImage1() {
  var image = document.getElementById('safari');  
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
      image.src = "safari.png";
    } else {
      image.src = "safariflat.png";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use setTimeout for this:

```
$('.box hammer').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
setTimeout(function() {
      changeImage1();
      // change time below to the time your animation takes
    }, 5000);
});

function changeImage1() {
  var image = document.getElementById('safari');  
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
      image.src = "safari.png";
    } else {
      image.src = "safariflat.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have to make sure that the hammer goes up in the same position as before, when it made the icon flat after a few seconds. How can I do that?

Comment: It depends, are your icon and your hammer two separate images? If so, how is the hammer moved?

Comment: They are seperated images, but I have already found a way. I'll do it with a .gif

Answer (score 1):

You can bind multiple `on` handlers to the same element and event, that's not a problem.

Delaying one of those handlers can be done in many ways, how is up to you. Libraries like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) and [lodash](https://lodash.com/) offer a number of delay types, such as [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce).

You should be able to use something like:

```js
function immediateHandler() {
  alert("Immediate handler!");
}

function lateHandlerImpl() {
  alert("Late handler!");
}

var lateHandler = _.delay(lateHandlerImpl, 2500);

$('div.button').on('click', immediateHandler);
$('div.button').on('click', lateHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button">Click Me!</div>
```

Replace the alerts with your logic (creating/switching the images) and change the timing to sync the image changes up, and you should be able to create a fairly convincing animation.

Comment: Any benefit to using a second handler rather than just using a timer?

Comment: @DelightedD0D In this case, probably not, but it splits the handler and delay logic nicely.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you explain the usage of `_` ? I've seen it used elsewhere like http://stackoverflow.com/a/28129275/1376624 for example, but I can't seem to find any reference to it's usage online I just keep finding stuff about `underscore.js`

Comment: @DelightedD0D That's exactly what it is: part of the underscore.js (or lodash) library. Both are linked in my answer.

Comment: Gotcha, so I guess adeneo's usage in the linked question was different as he wasn't using underscore. Thanks for your time!